# Android App Design - Synchronizing the GUI with a sequence of Sounds

Tags: android, multithreading, design-patterns, user-interface

I need some advice.  I’m building an app that has a sequence of 4 actions that will occur when the user presses a button.  As soon as the user presses GO, that button must become un-enabled, and some visual cues in the interface must show which of the 4 actions is taking place. (Changing the visibility of ImageView, for example)    The GUI must change immediately to keep in sync with sounds that are playing.

After each of the 4 actions, the GUI must change to reflect which of the actions is currently happening.

Current attempts – I can’t get the GUI to change before the first action starts (sound is playing), and at the appropriate times in between the actions.  The actions are to play 4 different sounds.  Currently, I’m using the MediaPlayer.

I haven’t had any luck trying to force the GUI to update when I want to.  I have used AsyncTask, and tried all combinations of setEnabled(), invalidate(), forceLayout(), refreshDrawableState() to try to force things to happen in the gui when I want them to – corresponding to the 4 sounds playing in sequence.

My problem seems to be that I’m trying to do 4 things in one onClick handler. I have been really struggling with validate() calling reDraw at "sometime in the future."

I don’t know what design pattern would be best suited to providing a visual cue to the 4 things that are happening in sequence.

I’m just starting to look at Handlers.  Is this the way to go?  I thought it would be easy.  Any advice?

Comment: "Adive" might include tutorials / books that I haven't read.  I'm working on the Commonsware books, so if there is a known helpful section in there, that would be useful.

Comment: I was hoping someone could answer this.

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect(int) [add the closing bracket in the end of the link, dont know why its ignoring the closing bracket with the link]
Also I found a useful tut:http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

Comment: Thanks Urban.  Those were helpful, especially the Vogella tutorials.  It seems that I simply didn't believe the lack of control the programmers can have on the main thread.  I created a simple Handler to put things on a sub-thread, and post back things that need to be on the main thread - changing the UI.  It did create one more problem.  Some code that was previously on teh main thread used a CoutnDownTimer, which now doesn't work when it's on a background thread.  Looper.prepare???  man oh man.  There's lots to learn.

Comment: Oh, you must be making changes to the UI within the background thread. That is not allowed. A background thread cannot make any direct interactions with the UI thread. You'll find loads of posts around here regarding this, and how to make a background thread handle the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods of the AsyncTask execute on the GUI thread. Doesn't updating the GUI from these methods work?

Comment: Yes, I'll accept this as an answer.  It's not very flexible, and not really scalable - the organization of the code feels very uncomfortable for old OO programmers.  Some combination of Handlers and AsyncTask depending on what you're doing.  My problem was believing that it has to be this difficult, but once you get going it's not that bad.....  Thanks!